# Rpi Zero W - What reasons to wifi not to load after power outage

Tags: raspbian, networking, linux, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I have 2 Rpis : Zero, Zero W. Both are running Strech Lite, in console mode, and serve a role in GPIO control in Home automation ( running `pigpiod` ).

Last night, both was shut down due to power outage, and went back on.

Rpi Zero - booted back on, connected to wifi- working as expected.

Rpi Zero W- boots OK, but not having `wlan0` when  executing `ifconfig`.

**Check#1**: switching SD cards - showd that the problem moved to other Rpi (meaning- it is not hardware issue )

**Check#2**: `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` contains wifi ssid, psk ,as needed to connect.

What else can be checked to fix it (eliminating it is not an hardware issue, but something went wrong with file system)?

Guy

Comment: What OS and version are you running? (Check with `uname -a`)

Comment: as said: strech lite

Comment: As a part of the troubleshooting, post info that is needed, log information, and isn't ifconfig replaced with "ip" in stretch?

Comment: @MatsK please specify what file exactly to show it contents, and what did you mean regarding ifconfig?

Comment: ???????????????

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you're using a realrek wireless adapter, if so I found the following thread in the Raspberry forum:

> I worked out how to fix this problem. It was also a problem for Fedora
>   25. There is a problem with the r8712u driver which is a 'staging' driver. It needs to be replaced with r92u driver. Look up 'r8712u fail
>   fedora 25' on google to get details. As it seemed to be a kernel
>   problem I reported it on the raspberry pi kernel page on github.

[Realtek wireless adapter not connecting in Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191844)

Solution found at given github link:

Install r92su kernel module replacing r8712u
Initial update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install kernel headers

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Install git

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Clone the rtl8192su repository

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/chunkeey/rtl8192su.git
```

Make r92su driver

```
cd rtl8192su
make -f Makefile.r92su
```

Create kernel module updates directory and copy new driver to it

```
UPDATES=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates
if [ ! -d $UPDATES ] ; then
sudo mkdir $UPDATES
echo creating $UPDATES
fi
sudo cp r92su/r92su.ko $UPDATES
```

Blacklist r8712u if not previously black listed

```
if [ ! -e /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8712u.conf ] ; then
sudo echo "blacklist r8712u" >/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8712u.conf
fi
```

update dependencies

```
sudo depmod
```

Reboot at this point to enable new driver to be used

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2185

*edited to adhere to etiquette

Comment: Hi, and welcome to raspberrypi.SE. While this might contain an answer to the questions, link-only answers are generally frowned upon. Links tend to rot, and this answer would be more usable, and future proof, if you would include the relevant parts of the link content here on the site.

Comment: @Sjoerd - thanks for your answer- but since long time has passed, I reinstalled SD , so I can't confirm it solves. Tnx again.